# 2005 BMO2 showing that at least three different sets in the list are subsets of at least four sets in X.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Consider the following problem:

> Let $X = \{A_1, A_2, … , A_n\}$ be a set of distinct 3-elements
> subsets of $\{1,2, … ,36\}$ such that
>
> 1. $A_i$ and $A_j$ have non-empty intersection for every $i, j$;
> 2. The intersection of all the elements of X is the empty set.
>
> - Show that $n ≤ 100$.
> - How many such sets $X$ are there when $n = 100$?

From the solution, assuming that $A_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$.
Choose $A_{i_1}$, $A_{i_2}$, $A_{i_3}$ with $1$ not in $A_{i_1}$, $2$ not in $A_{i_2}$ and $3$ not in $A_{i_3}$.
Suppose that $A_{i_1} = \{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$, $A_{i_2} = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ and $A_{i_3} = \{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$.
Every set in the collection $X$ has one of the following doubleton sets as a subset:
$$\{1, a_1\}, \{1, a_2\}, \{1, a_3\}, \{2, b_1\}, \{2, b_2\}, \{2, b_3\}, \{3, c_1\}, \{3, c_2\}, \{3, c_3\},$$
and call this list of subsets $(t)$.

I don’t understand the following part of the solution:

To show that at least three different sets in the list $(t)$ are subsets of at least four sets in $X$.
Suppose that at most two different sets in the list $(t)$ are subsets of at least four or more sets in $X$.
Every set in $X$ contains at least one set in list $(t)$, so the total number of sets in $X$ is at most $34\cdot2+7\cdot3=89<100=|X|$.  Therefore, there are at least three different sets $P1, P2$ and $P3$ in the list $(t)$ which are subsets of at least four sets in $X$.

Comment: 1) What do you not understand about the solution? What do you currently understand? 2) Can you link to the original writeup? It seems to be written in a slightly weird manner, so I'm wondering if this from an official solution.

Comment: As I'm reading the official solution, I don't understand the statement of "at least three different sets in the list (t) are subsets of at least four sets in X."  and the proof of it.

Comment: I understand that the result can be used to prove the cases of intersection of P1, P2 and P3 to find the final answer.

Comment: Can you link to the solution, or take a photo/screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant to a complete solution to the original problem.

It's my understanding/interpretation of the part of the solution that was shown.

---

Let's show that for all other configurations, $ n \leq 100$.
WLOG $A_1 = \{1, 2, 3 \}$.
Choose Ai1, Ai2, Ai3 with 1 not in Ai, 2 not in Ai2 and 3 not in Ai3.
Suppose that Ai1 = {a1, a2, a3}, Ai2 = {b1, b2, b3} and Ai3 = {c1, c2, c3}.
Every set in the collection X has at least one of the following doubleton sets as a subset: {1, a1}, {1, a2}, {1, a3}, {2, b1}, {2, b2}, {2, b3}, {3, c1}, {3, c2}, {3, c3} -----(t)
A pair may appear at most twice in this list.

For each of the 9 (not necessarily distinct) pairs $\{x,y\}$, let $T_{x,y }$ be the number of triples $A_i$ for which $\{x,y\}$ is a subset.

Claim: If $T_{x,y} < 4$  for at most 2 pairs of (t), then $ n \leq 100$.

Proof: Since each triple of X contains at least one of these subsets of (t), we can bound $n \leq \sum T_{x,y}$.
For the 2 pairs of (t) with $ T_{x,y} \geq 4$, they are contained in at most 34 triples of the form $\{x, y, z\}$.
For the other 7 pairs of (t) with $T_{x,y} < 4$, by definition, they are contained in at most 3 triples.
Thus, we have  $ n \leq 2 \times 34 + 7 \times 3 = 89 $ triples.

Corollary: If $n \geq 90$, then we must have $T_{x,y} \geq 4$ for at least 3 pairs of (t).

(I've not thought about how to continue form here.)

---

Note: Ideally this is stated at the start of the solution, to provide some motivation for how the thought process.

We provide an example where $ n = 100$ is possible. 
Take $ \{1, 2, 3 \}, \{1, 2, 4 \}, \{1, 3, 4 \}, \{2,3, 4 \}, \{ 1, x, y\}$ where $ x \in \{2, 3, 4 \}$, $y \in \{5, 6, \ldots \}$.
this gives $ 4 + 3 \times 32 = 100$ sets that fulfill the conditions of the problem.

Following the above approach, the first 4 sets correspond to $A_1, A_{i3}, A_{i2}, A_{i1}$.
The collection (t) is $ \{ 1, 2 \} \times 2, \{1, 3 \} \times 2, \{1, 4 \} \times 2, \{2, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{3, 4\}$.